# vba check if specific process task id is still running

Tags: ms-access, vba, shell

I am using the `Shell()` function to execute an external application in MS Access. `Shell()` returns a task ID of the specific process that was started.

I need a way to check if that process is still running or if it has closed. I'm sure that I will need to do some sort of windows API call but I can't seem to find anything just now.

Comment: A similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439200/480767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Access FAQ, and it was answered years and years ago on the FAQ site for comp.databases.ms-access, http://mvps.org/access/.

[API: Shell and Wait](http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0004.htm)

Comment: [64-Bit friendly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196131/155931)

Answer (score 2):

Shell `Tasklist`  (Description at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) is a good way to do it manually.  I'm not sure how you could interact with the list of PIDs by automation, though.  That's a bit more difficult.

Tip: If you just want to kill a process, use `Shell "TaskKill /F /IM ""excel.exe"""` to kill all open instances of MS Excel. Or `Shell "TaskKill /F /IM ""msaccess.exe"""` to kill all open instances of MS Access (including the Access file that hosts your VBA script, unfortunately).  This is how I end my standard issue Error Handler.

#### Edit

When you run it, you should something like:
[image]

Comment: When I run TaskList at the command prompt it isn't found. Is this an external application that I need to download? I can't seem to find any reference to this in the documentation.

Comment: Odd. Well, that link I provided is to the official documentation for WinXP.  Are you one of those lucky few to work in a company that has an OS younger than 7 years old?

Comment: I am running XP Home. Maybe it is a Pro app? That doesn't make much sense to me but that is all I can think of!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following as part of the WMI:

```
Public Function WaitForProcess(ProcessName As String, Optional ProcessID As Boolean = False)

    ' if you dont mind including the reference for Microsoft WMI Scripting V.1.2 Library, uncomment below
    ' Otherwise, it should work fine without the reference, just no intelasense

    UpdateStatus "Starting WaitForProcess function to wait for process: " & ProcessName

    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim colProcesses
    Dim objWMIService

    UpdateStatus "Use this computer to see processes on"
    strComputer = "."

    UpdateStatus "Impersonate this computer"
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    UpdateStatus "Get all running processes with a " & IIf(ProcessID = False, "Name", "ProcessID") & " of: " & ProcessName
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * " & _
                                               "FROM Win32_Process  " & _
                                               "WHERE " & IIf(ProcessID = False, "Name", "ProcessID") & " = '" & ProcessName & "'")

    UpdateStatus "Waiting untill there are no more instances of this process shown in the process list"
    Do
        DoEvents
        ' Update the collection of processes returned

        Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE " & IIf(ProcessID = False, "Name", "ProcessID") & " = '" & ProcessName & "'")


    Loop Until colProcesses.Count = 0

    UpdateStatus "The " & IIf(ProcessID = False, "Process Name", "Process ID") & ": " & ProcessName & " concluded successfully. WaitForProcess Completed"

End Function
```

This works well for my project; however, it does require Windows Management Instrumentation.