# Shell *.vbs from within VBA

Tags: vba, shell, vbscript

Hi can anyone tell me how to execute my .vbs from within VBA cause the following code dose not work.

```
RetBat4 = Shell("c:\VTS\QUEEN ANNES REVENGE\SYSTEM\VBS\UNDO_2.vbs", 1)
```

VBA debug says that the sytax is wrong????

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Shell("cscript ""c:\VTS\QUEEN ANNES REVENGE\SYSTEM\VBS\UNDO_2.vbs""",1)
```

If your VBS needs complete command shell environment, use this:

```
Shell("cmd /c cscript ""c:\VTS\QUEEN ANNES REVENGE\SYSTEM\VBS\UNDO_2.vbs""",1)
```

and if your program should wait until the VBS ends, read this post:

[VBA Shell and Wait with Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439200/vba-shell-and-wait-with-exit-code)

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
Set ws=CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
set ws.exec("ping " & ip & " -n 20")
set ws=nothing
```