# How to save Excel Workbook to Desktop regardless of user?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Workbook that on Form Button click I need to save a copy of the workbook to the user's Desktop.

Originally everything was going to be on a shared Network folder, but now I have about 6 different users that when they click the button, I need to save the workbook to their individual Desktops.

Is their a way (coding-wise) to save to the machine Desktop without having to specify individual users (which would require me to maintain 6 different Workbook files)?

Answer (score 49):

I think this is the most reliable way to get the desktop path which isn't always the same as the username.

```
MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
```

Comment: havent thought about that! +1

Comment: @mehow I've only thought about it in the past as mine isn't ;)

Comment: Will there need to be any special references, files, enabling needed to run that code on my users machines?

Comment: No, windows scripting runtime is part of the standard windows installation

Comment: Ok, thanks! Appears to be working :) One other question. I have an Archive feature that does basically the same thing, but places the file into a folder with the name of `FileName-Date`. Do you know how I could get the System username to make the filename more unique? Ex. `FileName-User-Date.xlsm`.

Comment: Use mehow's technique below `Environ("username")`

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that they each have their own machines, but if they need to log onto a co-workers machine, and then use the file, saving it through "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\" will make it available to different usernames.

```
Public Sub SaveToDesktop()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "_copy", _ 
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

I'm not sure whether this would be a requirement, but may help!

Comment: Thanks for the note, and certainly something worth considering in normal circumstances. These users are inspectors, roughly 6, each in charge of their own area in the state. The likelihood of them ever logging onto another inspectors machine is highly unlikely to probably never.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I use this way

```
Public bEnableEvents As Boolean
Public bclickok As Boolean
Public booRestoreErrorChecking As Boolean   'put this at the top of the module

 Private Declare Function apiGetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
"GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function GetUserID() As String
' Returns the network login name
On Error Resume Next
Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
Dim strUserName As String
strUserName = String$(254, 0)
lngLen = 255
lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
If lngX <> 0 Then
    GetUserID = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
Else
    GetUserID = ""
End If
Exit Function
End Function
```

This next bit I save file as PDF, but can change to suit

```
Public Sub SaveToDesktop()
Dim LoginName As String
LoginName = UCase(GetUserID)

ChDir "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\"
Debug.Print LoginName
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\MyFileName.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a bullet-proof way of doing it - your function `GetUserID()` returns the users login name (however the user profile folder may not be called the same thing in some circumstances)