# Issues accessing the user desktop using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, directory, desktop

I am trying to use VBA in order to save a file on a user's desktop.  I have found people requesting similar things on this site and others and the answers usually recommend using the following function to get the file path of the user's desktop

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

However, I tried this and all I get is a 424 Object required error.  The spreadsheet I am trying to add this to is long and complex so I created a new sheet with just the section of code I was interested in.

```
Sub TestMacro()

Dim Testy As String

Testy = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

MsgBox Testy

End Sub
```

When I run this macro I still get a 424 object required error.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is there something locked down in my office environment preventing me from using this command?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this : `MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")`

Comment: Or : `MsgBox Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"` one of them should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: How to save Excel Workbook to Desktop regardless of user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551238/vba-how-to-save-excel-workbook-to-desktop-regardless-of-user)

Comment: See duplicate question, the code you are trying to use is VB not VBA :)

Comment: Andreas - Both of these worked a charm - thanks!

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` is [tag:vb.net] not [tag:vba]

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code

```
Sub TestMacro()
    Set oWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MsgBox (oWSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"))
End Sub
```

Comment: As per the question above, above code will work. `Environment.GetFolderPath` is not a VBA