# How to set the extra workbook location as desktop?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save an extra workbook in desktop.

But it should be beware that many different user accounts for my company computers.This workbook should be suited for all users and stored on their user account desktop.

To be specific ,

my desktop location= `c:\Users\knd\Desktop`
Peter desktop location =`c:\Users\peterd\Desktop`

**Is it possible to do it ?**

```
strFileName = "c:\Users\(username)\Desktop"

wb.SaveAs strFileName
```

Comment: yes, try the code below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: How to save Excel Workbook to Desktop regardless of user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551238/vba-how-to-save-excel-workbook-to-desktop-regardless-of-user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the command:

```
Environ("Username")
```

Try the code below:

```
strFileName = "c:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Wscript.Shell to get the Desktop path.

```
Function getDeskTopPath() As String
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    getDeskTopPath = oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Reference: [WshShell.SpecialFolders](http://ss64.com/vb/special.html)

Additional Special Folders

```
  AllUsersDesktop
  AllUsersStartMenu
  AllUsersPrograms
  AllUsersStartup
  Desktop
  Favorites
  Fonts
  MyDocuments
  NetHood
  PrintHood
  Programs
  Recent
  SendTo
  StartMenu
  Startup
  Templates
```

Comment: You went all P.H.D level here :)

Comment: Lol...I prefer your answer because it is one line of code.  I just forget the syntax.