# Saving to current user desktop location

Tags: json, excel, vba

So I am using VBA-JSON in excel to convert excel data to json file. I have the filepath set to my desktop however I would like other users to be able to run the conversion as well.
I currently have this as a placeholder for the save location:

```
'change the path below to save where you desire
Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\user\Desktop\jsonExample.json", True)
jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3))
Exit Sub
```

I've done research and I've seen mentions of .specialfolders but I am uncertain where to put it in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked similar questions? (e.g. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/38966027/17172829)

Comment: You could use the [Environ function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function): `Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\jsonExample.json", True)`