# VBA - Saving to any users desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for the answer and read many responses but I am still lost. I have an `Excel` Document that I have set up a VBA `CommandButton` that exports the sheet to a PDF document and save to my desktop but as I need multiple users to access and save the document I am assuming it needs to find the users desktop and save there which will be different for different users.

I am currently using

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Sub SavePDF()     
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _                   
          Filename:="C:\Integration\Export.pdf", _        
          OpenAfterPublish:=True 
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I suggest you use a [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx) to get a target location, instead of hardcoding it. Also, do you mean to have a `Sub` declaration nested in another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Excel Workbook to Desktop regardless of user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551238/how-to-save-excel-workbook-to-desktop-regardless-of-user)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to save to users desktops. I typically do this to write temporary text files which I then delete, but it can be used for this as well:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Sub SavePDF()     
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _                   
          Filename:= Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Export.pdf", _        
          OpenAfterPublish:=True 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be the desktop you could use

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          Filename:=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Export.pdf", _
          OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

I'd rename the `CommandButton1` to something else - maybe `cmdExportPDF`, and as jsheeran suggest - lose the Sub `SavePDF()` line.