# How to get the email addresses from PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS with VBA

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

How can I get the email addresses from **PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS** using VBA?

I have been trying some regular expressions but I never worked with it and I am having some problems.

I need to retrieve the email address from "To:" and "From:" and "CC:"

Comment: Why do you need PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS  for this instead of the MailItem.Recipients collection?

Comment: Dimitri, can you tell me how can I get the SMTP email address of the sender?

Comment: What is wrong with `SenderEmailAddress` which is a regular property of `MailItem` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro below gets bigger every time I want to investigate a new mail item property.  I add the new property or properties, comment out those I do not need today, select a few relevant emails and run the macro. I can then examine the desktop file “DemoExplorer.txt” at my leisure.

I have added all the “non-standard” properties that seem relevant to your requirement.  Most seem duplicate of “standard properties”.  The only one that seems useful is the “To:” line of PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS.  The email addresses have been stripped out of the standard To property but they are present in the “To:” line.

Hope this helps.

```
Public Sub DemoExplorer()

  ' Outputs selected properties of selected emails to a file.

  ' ???????  No record of when originally coded
  ' 22Oct16  Output to desktop file rather than Immediate Window.
  ' Various  New properties added as necessary

  ' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
  ' http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283

  ' Source of PropertyAccessor information:
  ' https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/

  ' Needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime if "TextStream"
  ' and "FileSystemObject" are to be recognised

  Dim AttachCount As Long
  Dim AttachType As Long
  Dim FileOut As TextStream
  Dim Fso As FileSystemObject
  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxR As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim NumSelected As Long
  Dim Path As String
  Dim PropAccess As Outlook.propertyAccessor

  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

  Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FileOut = Fso.CreateTextFile(Path & "\DemoExplorer.txt", True)

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  NumSelected = Exp.Selection.Count

  If NumSelected = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      With ItemCrnt
        FileOut.WriteLine "--------------------------"
        FileOut.WriteLine "From (Sender): " & .Sender
        FileOut.WriteLine "From (Sender name): " & .SenderName
        FileOut.WriteLine "From (Sender email address): " & .SenderEmailAddress
        FileOut.WriteLine "Subject: " & CStr(.Subject)
        FileOut.WriteLine "Received: " & Format(.ReceivedTime, "dMMMyy h:mm:ss")
        FileOut.WriteLine "To: " & .To
        FileOut.WriteLine "CC: " & .CC
        FileOut.WriteLine "Recipients: " & .Recipients(1)
        For InxR = 2 To .Recipients.Count
          FileOut.WriteLine Space(12) & .Recipients(InxR)
        Next
        'FileOut.WriteLine "Text: " & Replace(Replace(Replace(.Body, vbLf, "{lf}"), vbCr, "{cr}"), vbTab, "{tb}")
        'FileOut.WriteLine "Html: " & Replace(Replace(Replace(.HtmlBody, vbLf, "{lf}"), vbCr, "{cr}"), vbTab, "{tb}")
        'AttachCount = .Attachments.Count
        'FileOut.WriteLine "Number of attachments: " & AttachCount
        'For InxA = 1 To AttachCount
        '  AttachType = .Attachments(InxA).Type
        '  FileOut.WriteLine "Attachment " & InxA
        '  FileOut.Write "  Attachment type: "
        '  Select Case AttachType
        '    Case olByValue
        '      FileOut.WriteLine "By value"
        '    Case olEmbeddeditem
        '      FileOut.WriteLine "Embedded item"
        '    Case olByReference
        '      FileOut.WriteLine "By reference"
        '    Case olOLE
        '      FileOut.WriteLine "OLE"
        '    Case Else
        '      FileOut.WriteLine "Unknown " & AttachType
        '  End Select
        '  ' I recall PathName giving an error for some types
        '  On Error Resume Next
        '  FileOut.WriteLine "  Path: " & .Attachments(InxA).PathName
        '  On Error GoTo 0
        '  FileOut.WriteLine "  File name: " & .Attachments(InxA).FileName
        '  FileOut.WriteLine "  Display name: " & .Attachments(InxA).DisplayName
        '  ' I do not recall every seeing a parent but it is listed as a property
        '  ' but for some attachment types it gives an error
        '  On Error Resume Next
        '  FileOut.WriteLine "  Parent: " & .Attachments(InxA).Parent
        '  On Error GoTo 0
        '  FileOut.WriteLine "  Position: " & .Attachments(InxA).Position
        'Next

        Set PropAccess = .propertyAccessor

        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0050001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS:" & vbLf & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_SENDER_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_DISPLAY_BCC: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E02001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_DISPLAY_CC: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E03001E")
        FileOut.WriteLine "PR_DISPLAY_TO: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E")

        Set PropAccess = Nothing
      End With
    Next
  End If

  FileOut.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Tony, With this can get the information I need. Thanks.