# Unable to download files from Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am unable to download file from Outlook. Getting error **"cannot save the attachment. You do not have appropriate permission"**. Given below line is throwing error.

ATMT.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\p2018\Desktop\mail folder"

Also sharing the code

```
Sub ExtracFiles()
Dim O As Outlook.Application 
Set O = New Outlook.Application`

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = O.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim Fol As Outlook.Folder
Set Fol = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Weekly Compliance 
Report")

Dim OMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Set OMAIL = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim ATMT As Outlook.Attachment
Dim mydate As Date
mydate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")


For Each OMAIL In Fol.Items
    For Each ATMT In OMAIL.Attachments
        If 
OMAIL.SenderEmailAddress="PeopleGroup@Check.com" And _ 
Format(OMAIL.ReceivedTime, _ 
 "mm-dd-yyyy") = mydate Then
            ATMT.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\p2018\Desktop\mail folder"

            MsgBox ATMT
        Else
        End If
    Next ATMT
 Next OMAIL

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you user "p2018"?  I have never tried but did not think you could access another user's desktop.  If I want to write to my desktop I use the technique I learnt from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the fully qualified filename, not just path:

```
ATMT.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\p2018\Desktop\mail folder\" & ATMT.FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Bringing this up again, but I've been encountering the very same error for the whole morning.

Turned out there was a file with the exact same name of the Outlook attachment, so it wouldn't let me overwrite it.

Saving the attachment with a different name works well.