# run time Error 91, object not set, trying to automatically download email attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to automatically download email attachments on outlook. I am receiving a run time error and I am not sure how to fix it. I am probably just missing something basic. I have been staring at this for way to long.

I tried having MItem as Outlook.MailItem in the brackets of Sub SaveAttachments but this caused the program to not load.

```
Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\______\Desktop\Test Folder"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

When I try to debug it highlights For Each oAttachment in MItem.Attachments

I inserted the ____ on purpose.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `Dim` statement with initialise `MItem` to `Nothing`.  You must set `MItem` to a mail item before trying to access that mail item's attachments.  There are four methods of identifying an mail item. (1) Use Explorer to access emails selected by user. (2) Read up or down a folder.  (3) Use a rule than runs a script. (4) Use an event.  Which method is best depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will be using a rule to run a script

Comment: The `MailItem` object needs to come from somewhere. Until the reference is initialized, `MItem` is `Nothing` and any member call against it will throw error 91.

Comment: How should I initialize it?

Comment: The way you have it now, you would have to fetch the mailitem from the inbox - and from your previous comment it looks like that's not what you want/need. @TonyDallimore gave you the other options already - I believe you want to pick a method that *gives you* the mailitem object to work with. Handling an event that's fired whenever a new email arrives, and gives you that mailitem object as a parameter, would be the simplest way I think.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: Replace `Sub SaveAttachments()` by `Public Sub SaveAttachments(ByRef MItem As Outlook.MailItem)`.  Delete `Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem`.  It is the rule that identifies the email to be processed.  It then passes a reference to this email when it calls `SaveAttachments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case my comment is not clear:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments(ByRef MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\______\Desktop\Test Folder\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    With oAttachment
      If LCase(Right$(.DisplayName, 4)) = ".csv" then
        .SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & .DisplayName
      End If
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Note 1: I have added "\" at the end of `sSaveFolder`.

Note 2: `SaveAsFile` overwrites any existing file with the same name.  This code will only work if `DisplayName` is always unique or if you are happy to lose the earlier file if `DisplayName` is reused.

Note 3: Signatures and images are held as attachments even if they are not listed as attachments for the user.  You should consider checking the extension to ensure you only save attachments you want.

Note 4: If I want to save a file on my desktop I use:

```
' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
'                     http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283

Dim Path As String
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

Comment: I finally got it working, thank you! How would I make it so it would only download say csv files?

Comment: I have added a test for an extension of "csv" or "CSV".  `Right$` extracts the last N characters of a string.  `LCase` converts any uppercase characters to lowercase.