# VBA code to split all unread emails in the main Outlook inbox randomly into subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

At work we get a number X of e-mails per day which must be handled by 4 people. I am trying to come up with a macro that, when run, takes X and splits it randomly and equally into 4 subfolders so that every person knows what they have to do. I don’t have any coding background and my Excel knowledge is basic at best. How would I start and is it even doable?

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not a code creation platform. Please add what have you tried and users in SO will help you with whats wrong in it or what a better way.

Comment: This site exists so programmers can help one another develop.  If someone wrote the code for you, would it help you develop?  No one knows everything.  Even the most knowledgeable regulars (of which I am not one) ask the occasion question.  There will be no question or answer here that exactly matches your requirement but all the components you need should be easy to find.

Comment: I assume you have a shared store containing folders: Inbox, Alice, Bernard, Christine and David.  You wish to read down Inbox and move every email to one the other four folders.  You will find lots of Q&As with code that reads down or up an Inbox.   By “down” I mean `For Inx = 1 to Count`.  By “up” I mean `For Inx = Count To 1 Step -1`.  You should be able to find an answer that explains why it is important to read up if you are going to move emails to other folders.

Comment: In a lot of answers, you will find something like:  `Set FldrInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(Inbox)`.  This is not the format you want.  The shared box will not be your default.  You need to find an example that looks something like: `Set FldrInbox = Session.Folders(SharedStoreName).Folders(Inbox)`.  Use the same format to reference the other four folders.

Comment: How are you going to divide the emails up fairly?  Unless there are an exact multiple of 4 emails every day, Alice will get the most and David will get the least.  How you going to move to emails to Alice, Bernard, Christine, David, Alice, Bernard, Christine, David until you have emptied Inbox one day and move emails to Bernard, Christine, David, Alice, Bernard, Christine, David, Alice the next day?.

Comment: Start your research and update you question with your progress.  People here will help but only if you show some effort.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the time you took to reply! I don’t expect or want people to write the code for me, but at the moment I simply don’t know where to start.

Comment: You identified correctly what the macro needs to do. Dividing fairly is not an issue. I have 2 ideas in mind: let X be the number of emails that need to be divided. If x/4 = not integer, then go back to the previous integer. So for instance, 365/4 = 91.25, only 91 emails would go to each inbox, with the leftovers remaining in the inbox.

Comment: The other idea is to set up a loop that would take email 1 and move it to Alice, email 2 to Bernard, email 3 to Christie and email 4 to David. Then repeat until there are no items that can be moved (unread emails in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Below is my pseudo-code for your requirement.  Can you understand what I am suggesting?  Can you suggest improvements?  Try to convert my pseudo-code to VBA and update your question with your progress.  I will respond with comments on your code if I think you are going wrong.

A issue to consider is where should this code be placed.  It could be an Outlook macro or an Excel macro.  An Outlook macro would be easier to write.  But to run it, you would have to open Outlook and run the macro.  With an Excel macro, you could create a specific workbook with an auto-run macro.  You would simply click the workbook to start it and the emails would be distributed.  A final message would tell how many emails had been distributed.  The Excel macro would require greater understanding of linking different Microsoft Office products and some understanding of events.

```
Dim FldrInbox as Folder
Dim FldrsTeam(1 To 4) as Folder
Dim InxEmail as Long
Dim InxTeam as Long

Set FldrInbox = Reference to Shared Inbox
Set FldrsTeam(1) = Reference To Alice’s folder
Set FldrsTeam(2) = Reference To Bernard’s folder
Set FldrsTeam(3) = Reference To Christine’s folder
Set FldrsTeam(4) = Reference To David’s folder

InxTeam = Random number between 1 and 4

For InxEmail = FldrInbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
  FldrInbox.Items(InxEmail).Move FldrsTeam(InxTeam)
  If InxTeam = 4 Then
    InxTeam = 1
  Else
    InxTeam = InxTeam + 1
  End If
Next
```

**Edit 1**

The code below demonstrates the second technique for finding folders.  It creates a file on your desktop containing an indented list of every store and folder to which you have access.  Note: some of these folders are “secret” and are not listed in your folder pane because there is nothing you, as a human, can do with these folders.  However, you could write a macro to access these folders if you wish.

I have lots of Outlook modules which I name for their contents.  In general, I have one module per task.  I also have some general modules.  This code comes from my “ModDemonstrations”.  You are just starting so you may not need several modules, but I have been writing Outlook VBA for 15 years and have lots of macros and organising them is essential.

This routine needs a reference to Microsoft Scripting Library.  If you do not know what that means, I will add an explanation.

Run `ListStoresAndAllFolders()` and a file will be created on your desktop named “ListStoresAndAllFolders.txt”.  You do not need this code today, but I believe you will find it helpful for the future.  It uses recursion.  Look up recursion.  If you do not understand the explanations you find, I will try to write my own explanation.

Note that I write `Dim FldrCrnt As Outlook.Folder`.  There are two types of Folder: Outlook and Scripting.  A Scripting.Folder is a disc folder.  If you progress to copying information from Outlook folders to disc folders, you must be careful to specify which type of folder you mean.

```
Sub ListStoresAndAllFolders()

  ' Displays the name of every accessible store
  ' Under each store, displays an indented list of all its folders

  ' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
  ' http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283

  ' Needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime if "TextStream"
  ' and "FileSystemObject" are to be recognised

  Dim FileOut As TextStream
  Dim FldrCrnt As Outlook.Folder
  Dim Fso As FileSystemObject
  Dim InxFldrChild As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long
  Dim Path As String
  Dim StoreCrnt As Outlook.Folder

  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

  Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FileOut = Fso.CreateTextFile(Path & "\ListStoresAndAllFolders.txt", True)

  With Application.Session
    For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
      Set StoreCrnt = .Folders(InxStoreCrnt)
      With StoreCrnt
        FileOut.WriteLine .Name
        For InxFldrChild = .Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
          Set FldrCrnt = .Folders(InxFldrChild)
          Call ListAllFolders(FldrCrnt, 1, FileOut)
        Next
      End With
    Next
  End With

  FileOut.Close

End Sub
Sub ListAllFolders(ByRef Fldr As Folder, ByVal Level As Long, ByRef FileOut As TextStream)

  ' This routine:
  '  1. Output name of Fldr
  '  2. Calls itself for each child of Fldr
  ' It is designed to be called by ListStoresAndAllFolders()

  Dim InxFldrChild As Long

  With Fldr
    FileOut.WriteLine Space(Level * 2) & .Name
    For InxFldrChild = .Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
      Call ListAllFolders(.Folders(InxFldrChild), Level + 1, FileOut)
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your effort! I am currently reading up on loops to understand your pseudocode. For now the biggest issue is that I’m not sure how to reference the shared inbox, as NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder links to my own inbox.

Comment: @BogdanVulturu  There are different ways of finding a folder.  I rarely use GetDefaultFolder because it often does not link to the folder I expect.  I am a home user with two email addresses neither of which is the default.  A folder has two "child" properties: Folders and Items.  Folders is a collection of all the folder's sub-folders.  Items is a collections of an the items within a folder.  For Inbox all the items will be MailItems.   You can loop down Folders to find all the child folders.

Comment: The third technique is the one you will require.  NameSpace.Folders("NameOfStore").Folders("NameOfFolderWithinStore").  You can have Folders(A).Folders(B).Folders(C) ... to any depth.

Comment: @BogdanVulturu.  I have added code that demonstrates the second technique.  You do not need this technique at the moment but I believe you will find it helpful later.  I think I have given you enough of a clue for you to discover how to use the third technique.  I will be more specific if necessary.