# Vba runs on one pc but not another - "run time error 1004"

Tags: excel, vba

I have an invoicing template with a macro that exports the invoice as pdf as well as saves a copy as xlsx.

This macro runs fine on my pc but presents a run time error when used on a different pc. See the vba code.

The debug highlights the line from ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _

```
Sub SavePDFandXLSX()

    Dim user As String, strPath As String, strName As String 
    user = Environ("username")
    strPath = "C:\Users\" & user & "\Desktop\"
    strName = "Inv" & Range("Invoice_num").Value & "_" & Range("Invoice_client").Value

    
    If IsEmpty(Range("Invoice_date").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please input date - export failed"
    Else
    'do nothing
    End If
    'Test for blank/empty info
    If IsEmpty(Range("Invoice_client").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please input client - export failed"
    Else
    'do nothing
    End If
    If IsEmpty(Range("Invoice_description").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please input description - export failed"
    ElseIf Range("Invoice_description") Like "*Project service or description*" Then
        MsgBox "Please input description - export failed"
    'do nothing
    End If
    
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strPath & strName & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Sheets("Invoice").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strName & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
    
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Export complete! Do you want to clear the Invoice? This cannot be undone...", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Export complete")
    If answer = vbYes Then
    Call CopytoInvoicesExportedandClear
    Else
    'do nothing
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Other macros in this workbook work fine on both pc's
Appreciate any support.

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: Which version of Office does the other PC have?

Comment: Does `strPath & strName & ".pdf"` resolve to a valid path?

Comment: Does the pathe exist identical on both machines? User?

Comment: Note that the userprofile is not necessarily stored in `C:\Users\<username>` and the desktop folder is not necessarily  `C:\Users\<username>\desktop`

Comment: Both pcs are using Office 2021.  strPath & strName & ".pdf" resolves, the macro functions as desired on PC 1. Could someone suggest a different method to path to desktop across pcs / users?

Comment: Why don't you let the user choose the directory where the pdf should be saved. Not everyone wants files to be saved on the desktop ... there are tons of code snippets for that around

Comment: Try `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/7599798)