# Formatting email body from Excel contents

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a worksheet with given data,
[image]

I need to email the data using Microsoft Outlook in the required format for a specific date.

Say the date is 05 Jan 2015.
[image]

This is how the email should look,
[image]

The code is written in the modules of the Excel 2007 workbook,

```
Public Function FormatEmail(Sourceworksheet As Worksheet, Recipients As Range, CoBDate As Date)

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rows As Range

    On Error GoTo FormatEmail_Error

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each rows In Recipients.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        If rows.value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = rows.value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Hi All, " & vbNewLine & _
                         vbNewLine
                .display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing

        End If

    Next rows

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

FormatEmail_Error:

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure FormatEmail of Module modOutlook"

End Function
```

Comment: What needs to be added/changed in order to Paste only the Lines where in column A the value is NON-Zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create nicely formatted Outlook emails then you need to generate emails with formatting. Pure text-based-emails are evidently not sufficient and hence you must be looking for HTML formatted emails. If that's the case you probably aim to dynamically create HTML code with your VBA to mimic the nice visual representation of Excel.

Under the following link http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/ you'll find an online HTML editor which allows you to prepare a nicely formatted email and then shows you the HTML code which is necessary to get this formatting. Afterwards you just need to set in VBA the email body to this HTML code using

```
.HTMLBody = "your HTML code here"
```

instead of

```
.Body = "pure text email without formatting"
```

If that is not sufficient and you want to copy / paste parts of your Excel into that email then you'll have to copy parts of your Excel, save them as a picture, and then add the picture to your email (once again using HTML). If this is what you want then you'll find the solution here:
[Using VBA Code how to export excel worksheets as image in Excel 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003)

Comment: This is right and partial. I have provided the full code. This website do help http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for that serves the purpose. The html body is build using string builder concept and the email is formed as required(Altered the sub of email from the post). This is working fine.

> ```
> Public Function FormatEmail(Sourceworksheet As Worksheet, CoBDate As Date, FinalRatioLCR As Variant, FinalRatioAUD As Variant)
>
> Dim OutApp As Object
> Dim OutMail As Object
> Dim eMsg As String
>
> Dim ToRecipients As String
>
>    On Error GoTo FormatEmail_Error
>
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
>
> Dim Matrix2_1, Matrix2_2, Matrix2_3, Matrix3_1 As String
> Dim FinanceAllCurrency, AllCurrencyT1, AllCurrencyT0, AllCurrencyAUD As Double
>
> 'FinanceAllCurrency = FinalRatioLCR
> AllCurrencyT1 = 10.12
> AllCurrencyT0 = 20.154
> 'AllCurrencyAUD = FinalRatioAUD
> Matrix2_1 = "<td>" & FinalRatioLCR & "</td>"
> Matrix2_2 = "<td>" & AllCurrencyT1 & "</td>"
> Matrix2_3 = "<td>" & AllCurrencyT0 & "</td>"
> Matrix3_1 = "<td>" & FinalRatioAUD & "</td>"
>
> eMsg = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:" & _
>         "collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
>         "<table style=""width:50%""><tr>" & _
>         "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">LCR</th><th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">Finance</th>" & _
>          "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">Desk T+1</th><th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">Desk T+0</th></tr><tr>" & _
>         "<td>All Currency</td>" & Matrix2_1 & Matrix2_2 & _
>          Matrix2_3 & _
>         "</tr><tr><td>AUD Only</td>" & Matrix3_1 & "<td>-</td>" & _
>         "<td> &nbsp; &nbsp;  -  &nbsp;</td></tr></Table></body>"
>
>
> ToRecipients = GetToRecipients
>
>    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
>    
>   
>       With OutMail
>                 .To = ToRecipients
>                 .Subject = " Report -" & CoBDate
>                 .HTMLBody = "Hi All, " & "<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>" & _
>                            eMsg
>                 .display
>                 
>        End With
>        
>      On Error GoTo 0
>      
>      Set OutMail = Nothing
>
>    On Error GoTo 0
>    Exit Function
>
> FormatEmail_Error:
>
>     Set OutApp = Nothing
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
>     MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure FormatEmail of Module modOutlook"
>
> End Function
> ```

Recipients adress is dynamically retrieved from a range.

> ```
> Private Function GetToRecipients() As String
> Dim rngRows As Range
> Dim returnName As String
>
> For Each rngRows In shMapping.Range(MAPPING_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS).rows
>
> If Len(returnName) = 0 Then
>     returnName = rngRows.Cells(, 2).value2
> ElseIf Len(rngRows.Cells(, 2).value2) > 0 Or rngRows.Cells(, 2).value2 Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
>     returnName = returnName & ";" & rngRows.Cells(, 2).value2
> End If
>
> Next
> GetToRecipients = returnName
> End Function
> ```

Comment: What needs to be added/changed in order to Paste only the Lines where in column A the value is NON-Zero?