# Sending outlook mails from excel without cells

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I the below VBA code which generates a mail from different cells in an excel spreadsheet. The problem is that when I use it to generate an email, the mails will not fit to automatically to the screen like a normal outlook mail does. So if I read it on a smartphone screen the text won't fit to the screen.

There's a macro that sends the mail and a function that selects the range.

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

Dim rng As Range
Dim StrBody As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
'add this for the text string
'StrBody = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value & "<br>" & _
 '         Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value & "<br>" & _
  '        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Value & "<br><br><br>"

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
'You can also use a sheet name
'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "...." ' email adress here


' Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A18")
    .cc = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "The short update"
    '.HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


   Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
 ' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Row In rng
For Each Column In Row
StrBody = StrBody & " " & Column
Next
StrBody = StrBody & "<br>"
Next
```

You probably want something along the lines of the above code.
Even manually entered tables don't autofit.
If you're really trying to keep the format you might consider exporting the range to a shape and converting it to a picture. [Good luck with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16144168/3819867)