# How to convert columns with charts to txt file C++

Tags: c++, excel, xlsx

I have a xlsx file and there are a few columns from in that I want to read in via C++ and export to a txt file. some of the cells have charts within them. Is there a way in C++ to basically say from C3 to F5 copy and paste as a picture in the new txt file in code? The only things I've been able to find are things you have to pay for to i/o to xlsx files.

Comment: Do you want to paste a picture in a text file?

Comment: Yes if that's possible just so that the formatting looks the same

Comment: A [text-file (per definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) contains only text without any formatting.Yet, you could [export the given range as a picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003) file. But then the file wouldn't be a text file anymore. Alternatively, you could create your own file type which contains the data within the range and the formatting you need to recreate something similar in C++. But then it would be your file-type and not a text-file (text without formatting).

Comment: Do you want to get a picture of charts?

Comment: @Pavel yes, I want to get a picture of the charts in the certain cells. Or be able to recreate them into the text file using the data it uses.