# Save XLS as image with PHP

Tags: php, image, export, phpexcel

I have an XLS file an I need to export an area from that as image, like A1:K15 
I want to do that with PHP
I'm already using PHPExcel to read/write spreadsheets but i've no idea if it is possible somehow with that.
Any idea?

Comment: You will have to create an image yourself using PHP Functions.  Try this :  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options :

1. If you work with Windows Server, and you can install Excel on the Server - So you can open Excel as "[COM](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php)" , and then export your range.
2. Same as 1 - but do it with VBS file, that will connect to Excel , and not directly to Excel - it is the same sytax like VBA, so you can see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003).
3. Microsoft offer EWA - Excel Web Access , and in their API - their is an option to save range as image - exactly what you wanted , but the excel file need to hosted in Microsoft Sharepoint Online ( or SharePoint On Permise)
4. By PHPExcel - export to Html, and after that convert the html to image by wkhtmltoimage - it is command line tool that is part of wkhtmltopdf.

If  PDF is ok, you can use PHPExcel - To [export to PDF](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-pdf.php)