# Excel VBA Center header/footer "Align Left"

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to align Center Header in Excel? I know there is no any built in solution but is there any VBA code that would work. I have been trying copying cells to header, setting center header with VBA but my Center Header is "Align Center" all the time.

I have even found very complex code to calculate length of sentences and add spaces to each row but it doesn't really work correctly.

I can also set rows to repeat on top and forget about header but what about footer then? How I can set Center Footer to align my two row text to align left?

I have tried:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = Range("a1").Value & " " & Range("b1").Value & " " & Range("a2").Value & " " & Range("b2").Value
End With
```

Also sending named range to header:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetCenterHeader()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim myRow As Range

    With Range("NorthHead") ' reference named range
        For Each myRow In .Rows ' loop through referenced range rows
            txt = txt & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myRow.Value)), " ") & vbLf ' update 'txt' with current row cells values joined and separated by a blank
        Next
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1) ' set CenterHeader with resulting 'txt' excluding last vblf character
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Result is always the same:

[image]

Comment: May try the workaround method by trying to put center header text in some blank left aligned cells, then `Range.CopyPicture` of the cells and export them as jpg. Finally put the jpg with `PageSetup.CenterHeaderPicture`.May refer to  [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.centerheaderpicture) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try the following workaround and modify to your requirements

```
Sub test2()
Dim CenHd1 As String, CenHd2 As String, Fname As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Sht As Worksheet, MnSht As Worksheet
Dim Cht As ChartObject

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Set MnSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set Rng = Sht.Range("F1:F2")
CenHd1 = "Excel"
CenHd2 = "I am already left Aligned"
Sht.Range("F1").Value = CenHd1
Sht.Range("F2").Value = CenHd2
Sht.Activate
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    With Rng
    .Columns.AutoFit   'added after taking trial snapshot to perfectly center and left align        
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Font.Name = "Bookman Old Style"
    .Font.Size = 12
    'May specify other visual effects
    End With
Rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

Set Cht = Sht.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, Rng.Width * 1.01, Rng.Height * 1.01)
Cht.Name = "TmpChart"
Sht.Shapes("TmpChart").Line.Visible = msoFalse
Cht.Chart.Paste

Fname = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CentHead " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy hh-mm-ss") & ".jpg"
Cht.Chart.Export Filename:=Fname, Filtername:="JPG"
DoEvents
Cht.Delete
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True

MnSht.Activate
With MnSht.PageSetup.CenterHeaderPicture
        .Filename = Fname
        '.Height = 275.25
        '.Width = 463.5
        '.Brightness = 0.36
        '.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
        '.Contrast = 0.39
        '.CropBottom = 0
        '.CropLeft = 0
        '.CropRight = 0
        '.CropTop = 0
    End With

'Enable the image to show up in the center header.
MnSht.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&G"
'for Trial only
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView
' Clear junk files
If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Kill (Fname)
End Sub
```

Tried as follows
[image]

the code could also be modified as a function / procedure with parameters for repeated use with different Sheets, Workbooks etc. Hope it will help to serve the purpose.