# Save Image from clipboard using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, clipboard, powershell-4.0

I am trying to save image from clipboard to the file path. I have tried below script and it is returning "clipboard does not contain image data".

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
if ($([System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsImage())) {
    $image = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage()
    $filename='e:\test\test.png'         

    [System.Drawing.Bitmap]$image.Save($filename, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
    Write-Output "clipboard content saved as $filename"
} else {
    Write-Output "clipboarsd does not contains image data"
}
```

As the `Clipboard` class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode.

I have tried to run the script in

```
powershell -NoProfile -Sta -File $file
```

Also, I have tried to relaunch if runspace is not STA, this didn't help.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
if ($host.Runspace.ApartmentState -ne "STA") {
    "Relaunching"
    $file = "./saveImage.ps1"
    powershell -NoProfile -Sta -File $file 
    return
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In PowerShell 5.1 you can use Get-clipboard

```
 get-clipboard -format image
 $img = get-clipboard -format image
 $img.save("c:\temp\temp.jpg")
```

this should work too:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$clipboard = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetDataObject()
if ($clipboard.ContainsImage()) {
    $filename='c:\temp\test3.png'         
    [System.Drawing.Bitmap]$clipboard.getimage().Save($filename, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
    Write-Output "clipboard content saved as $filename"
} else {
    Write-Output "clipboard does not contains image data"
}
```

Comment: the second snippet is not working, it throw an error, see: https://imgur.com/nPDy1Sx

Comment: Small optimization for the first snippet: 

> $img = Get-Clipboard -format image
  if(!$img)
  {
    Write-Host "No File in clipboard."
    return
  }
  $img.save("D:\Temp\temp.jpg")

Comment: $img.save("c:\temp\temp.jpg") # It will not be a .jpg file. It will be .png in really.

Comment: PowerShell 7's `Get-Clipboard` does not include a `-Format` option.