# Increase quality of print screen of userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for copying userform and pasting it to Users desktop as a pdf file. Pdf file is OK, however quality of image inside it is quite bad. Is there any way to increase the quality of image inside pdf file?

```
Private Sub btnPrintPDF_Click()
'change to your button name
    Dim pdfName As String
    Dim newWS As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0

    DoEvents 'Otherwise, all of screen would be pasted as if PrtScn rather than Alt+PrtScn was used for the copy.

    Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
With newWS.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesTall = 1
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
    newWS.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    pdfName = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P14").Value & "," & " " & "Summary" & "_" & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".pdf"
newWS.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=pdfName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
    newWS.Delete
    Unload Me

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried using different file types, or image types?  bitmap versus jpeg versus png, for example, each are important for different types of images.  [Here's a link that might help with saving as a jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003).

Comment: I would like to try, but I don't get it how to change it to jpeg or any other. I don't have any extension in the code (jpeg, png). It just `Format:="Bitmap"` - How to change that to jpeg?

Comment: [Worksheet.PasteSpecial method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial).  You should be able to call the format by number, such that format:=4 is for bitmap, or format:=0 is png, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason only `format:=0` works. It is much better, but would be nice to try jpeg `format:=1` as well.

Comment: Why? JPEG will always result in a lower quality image because it uses a lossy compression scheme. It certainly won't result in a better quality image

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad png seems to be excessive for an image of a userform, but should have the most definition.  I understand that JPEG uses irreversible/lossy compression, and my immediate comment was thinking it was compressed bitmap (i forgot it could also be uncompressed), which is also irreversible (similar, but different... might have made a difference).  Came back with a better, more appropriate option, so that should circumvent any issue with irreversible compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from comments section:

*[Worksheet.PasteSpecial method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial). You should be able to call the format by number, such that format:=4 is for bitmap, or format:=0 is png, etc*

Corrected line appears:

```
newWS.PasteSpecial Format:=0, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```