# Excel VBA working in F8 but not in F5 mode

Tags: excel, vba

I read through several threads regarding the same problem but they all seemed to have different solutions and I couldn't apply them to my code. I also tested the code with `Application.Wait (Time + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` and `DoEvents` between all the lines in the 'EXPORT' section.

When I run the code with F5, a blank picture is exported. When I run it step by step with F8, the correct picture is exported. When I skip through with F8 very quickly, it also doesn't work. I tried to work out which line doesn't allow to be executed too quickly but failed.

**EDIT**
Adding `chartobj.Activate` before `chartobj.Chart.Paste` helped!
[Hint in a comment on this thread...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003)

```
Sub ExportSingleImage()
    'Plotplan Export Single Script v. 2.3

    Dim sheet, zoom_coef, area, chartobj
    Dim exportpath, prefix As String
    Dim sView, rr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim leadingzeros As Boolean

    'Export Path (with trailing backslash)
    exportpath = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Config").Range("B2")

    'Prefix
    prefix = ""

    'Tankstellennummern Länge
    idnumber_max = 6

    'Leading Zeros
    leadingzeros = False

    'Print Area
    rr = "B2:AI38"

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Nothing to configure after here
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Ask if existing files should be overwritten
    overwrite = MsgBox("Existierende Dateien überschreiben?", vbYesNoCancel)
    If overwrite = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'Error when the sheetname is longer than the allowed max
    If Len(xWs.Name) > idnumber_max Then
        prompt = "Bezeichnung zu lang: " & xWs.Name & " (Maximal " & idnumber_max & " Stellen.)"
        MsgBox (prompt)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if export folder exists. If not, create it.
    If Dir(exportpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir exportpath
    End If

    'Assemble full path with filename
    If leadingzeros Then
        exportpath = exportpath & prefix & Right("000000" & xWs.Range("AJ47").Value, idnumber_max) _
            & " - " & xWs.Range("AJ43").Value & ".png"
    Else
        exportpath = exportpath & prefix & xWs.Range("AJ47").Value _
            & " - " & xWs.Range("AJ43").Value & ".png"
    End If

    'Check if file already exists or "overwrite" had been selected by the user
    If Dir(exportpath) = "" Or overwrite = vbYes Then

        ' -- EXPORT --

        'Captures current window view
        sView = ActiveWindow.View

        'Sets the current view to normal so there are no "Page X" overlays on the image
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Temporarily disable screen updating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Selection Print Area
        xWs.PageSetup.PrintArea = xWs.Range(rr).Resize(xWs.Range(rr).Rows.Count, xWs.Range(rr).Columns.Count).Address

        'Export print area as correctly scaled PNG image, courtasy of Winand
        'Lukasz: zoom_coef can be constant = 0 to 5 can work too, but save is 0 to 4

        zoom_coef = 2 '100 / sheet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom

        Set area = xWs.Range(xWs.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        area.CopyPicture xlPrinter  'xlBitmap
        Set chartobj = xWs.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
        chartobj.Chart.Paste
        chartobj.Chart.Export exportpath, "png"
        chartobj.Delete

        'Returns to the previous view
        ActiveWindow.View = sView

        'Re-enables screen updating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference

Comment: Found the solution. See edit.