# VBA - Save SAPI speech to a GIVEN file type?

Tags: vba, excel, speech

**My Task**

It's possible to use speech in Office applications. My goal to save MS SAPI speech to a given file type. AFAIK my code example saves to a WAV file.

**Problem**

I don't know, if it's possible to define the wanted file type extension only or if it's necessary to do some further setting.
I didn't find an appropriate solution using VBA.

**Question**
Is there a code example how to precisely define a wanted file type, e.g. MP3, save a given text to this file type using the necessary settings (AudioStream)?

**Code**

In this code example I' m naming the output file directly as WAV with full uncertainty if this will be a WAV file.

I used late binding and included a comment to early binding, too.

```
Private Sub Speech2WAV()
' Purpose: save text Voice object to file
' Idea:    cf. .Net Article with some adaptions http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/samples/article.php/c13893/Text-to-Speech-Using-Windows-SAPI.htm
' Declare variables
  Dim s            As String
  s = "Could you give me a code example to save this text to a defined file type?"

'' ----------------------------------------------
'' Early Binding - reference do MS Speech Object Lib (SAPI.dll) needed
'' ----------------------------------------------
'  Dim oVoice       As New SpeechLib.SpVoice
'  Dim cpFileStream As New SpeechLib.SpFileStream
'' ----------------------------------------------

' ----------------------------------------------
' Late Binding
' ----------------------------------------------
  Dim oVoice       As Object
  Dim cpFileStream As Object

  Set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  Set cpFileStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")

' ----------------------------------------------

10   cpFileStream.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.wav", _
                   SpeechLib.SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite, False
20   Set oVoice.AudioOutputStream = cpFileStream
30   Set oVoice.Voice = oVoice.GetVoices.Item(0)
40   oVoice.Volume = 100
50   oVoice.Speak s, _
                  SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault
55   oVoice.Rate = 1        ' speed
56   oVoice.Volume = 100    ' volume

60   Set oVoice = Nothing
70   cpFileStream.Close
80   Set cpFileStream = Nothing
Exit Sub
OOPS:       ' Error Handler
     MsgBox "ERL=" & Erl & "|ErrNo=" & Err.Number & "|" & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in Speec2WAV"
End Sub
```

**Note**

Thx to @ashleedawg ['s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790329/why-does-application-speech-speak-read-some-numbers-individually-rather-than-put/48791412?noredirect=1#comment91809354_48791412) I can recommend the following links to the MS Speech API:

-[White papers SAPI 5.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717038(v%3dvs.85))

-[Microsoft Speech API 5.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-at/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee125663(v%3dvs.85))

Comment: you have not stated clearly what you are trying to do. .... your question is vague. it is unclear what you are actually asking.... your code saves to wav ... if you do not set AudioOutputStream, then it outputs to speakers

Comment: My code works and saves to an Audio file of an unsure file type, even if naming it test.WAV. I want to save to a programmatically defined file type and am asking for help how to code that including AudioOutputStream. I will reformulate my question.

Comment: it is a wav file. if you open the resulting file with a text editor like Notepad++ then you will see that the file signature bytes (first few bytes) match those that are used by wav files.

Comment: sapi only generates wav files. .... use `ffmpeg` to convert to other formats .... https://ffmpeg.org/  .... example of usage in vba ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899482/use-ffmpeg-in-vba-to-change-video-format#17065518

Comment: i must say that i learned something from you. i did not know that VBA allowed the use of line numbers

Comment: You are welcome. If you are interested in an alternative approach to analyze VBE including line numbers (so called ERLs) via XML, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743203/vba-find-all-numbered-lines-in-vbe-modules-via-pattern-search. Thx for your helpful ffmpeg hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sapi only generates wav files.

use ffmpeg to convert to other formats ... http://ffmpeg.org

example of usage in vba ... [use ffmpeg in vba to change video format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899482/use-ffmpeg-in-vba-to-change-video-format#17065518)