# Execute a command in command prompt using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, shell, command-line

I have a fixed command which i need to pass to command prompt using VBA and then the command should run.
e.g. "perl a.pl c:\temp"

following is the command i am trying to use but it just opens command prompt and doesn't run the command.

`Call Shell("cmd.exe -s:" & "perl a.pl c:\temp", vbNormalFocus)`

Please check.

Comment: you don't actually even need to open up cmd.exe first -> Shell() can pass your perl args straight to perl.exe

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The S parameter does not do anything on its own.

```
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below) 
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates  
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Try something like this instead

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "perl a.pl c:\temp", vbNormalFocus)
```

You may not even need to add "cmd.exe" to this command unless you want a command window to open up when this is run. Shell should execute the command on its own.

```
Shell("perl a.pl c:\temp")
```

**-Edit-**
To wait for the command to finish you will have to do something like @Nate Hekman shows in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/excel-vba-wait-for-shell-command-to-complete)

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /C perl a.pl c:\temp", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Comment: Keep in mind that shell will return after launching the process. It will not wait for your Perl-Script to finish, just saying.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this works fine. What would be the code to "wait for my Perl-Script to finish"?

Comment: I think would have to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/excel-vba-wait-for-shell-command-to-complete)

Comment: If instead of fixed command, I need to pass one of the variables from excel cells then how do i do that?
As of now, i have tried in following manner(X is variable)

**wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /C perl a.pl" & X & "100", windowStyle, waitOnReturn**

Comment: Another way to wait for a command to finish is to use the CreateProcessA function. For the VBA code, see this Microsoft article, "Determine when a shelled process ends," https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/determine-when-a-shelled-process-ends