# How to make a command button in word open a file using VB

Tags: vba, ms-word, commandbutton

So basically, I opened Microsoft Word and I went to the developer tab, drew a command button, double clicked it to open VB to write code, I want it to open a specific file. This is the code I wrote

Does not work...

My code I got so far is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Process.Start ("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
End Sub
```

When I click run it comes up with a error saying:

```
Run-time error '424':
Object required
```

Can you please fix for me because I have no idea... I just need this one button and that's all.

Comment: `Process.Start` is VB.NET, not VBA.  Look at `Shell`

Comment: simple google search would bring you to the answer, why does no one use search before they post?!?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918  KB article on shellexecute or use the stackoverflow on for using shell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

ok this is what you need my friend...

1. CREATE a new module - if you don't already have one:

   - to do this - its simply done in visual basic
   - then, press: ALT > select: Insert (menu) > select: Module
   - Note: you can change the module name via the properties window - for this example left it default 'Module1'
2. WRITE up a PUBLIC sub (as below):

   ```
   Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
       Dim strProgramName As String
       Dim strArgument As String

       strProgramName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
       strArgument = "/G"

       Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
   End Sub
   ```
3. CALL the sub in the click command private sub:

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       Module1.StartExeWithArgument
   End Sub
   ```

ok, enjoy ;)