# How to open default (X) mail client along with to, cc, bcc, html body & attachment of active workbook using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, email, excel

We have a requirement like we need to open default mail (what ever may be like : MS Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird,Windows Live Mail, Opera Mail etc. ) along with to, cc, bcc, html body & attachment of active workbook on a button click in Excel using VBA.

Thanks in advance. if any one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba) method passing the [mailto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) string. See [How to use command line switches to create a pre-addressed e-mail message in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/KB/287573?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Also you may consider automating Outlook. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for a sample code.

Comment: Thank u very much Eugene Astafiev, this excel vba may run in different environments, the mail client may not be Outlook there.

Comment: Could you please share more how to know which mail client is there and how to execute the Shell command for different mail client as I mention in my question...

Comment: There is no need to detect the default email client. It will be invoked automatically using the mailto command.