# How to write message to command window from VBA?

Tags: vba, cmd

I have a simple requirement

I want to write **'Hello world'** to windows `cmd.exe` from VBA (excel)

I referred 'Shell' and few other posts but could not do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command in command prompt using excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba)

Comment: What's the goal? you can use `Shell "cmd.exe /S /K echo Hello World"`

Comment: @Reza Yes it worked and in addition to that I also posted my version

Answer (score 2):

The following worked:

```
strToPrint = "Hello World!"
Shell "cmd.exe /K echo " & strToPrint, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: Fantastic answer