# Embed powershell script in VBA macro and run it from there

Tags: vba, powershell, cmd

I am trying to write this neat little bit of code and am having some massive issues with the last bit of it. So the intention was to write a code that would go into all the .zip files in a folder, find a folder in each by name, go inside, find a file ending in "_nl.inp" and copy it outside the archive.

While digging for ideas as far as VBA goes I could only find how to unzip the entire archive and not just pinpoint the file and pull i out. But I managed to find how to do this in powershell language. So I wrote a powershell script which works beautifully. That script is below.

```
$zZipFileName = "C:\Users\ccapsun2\Desktop\New loads formatting\load decks"
      $shap = new-object -com shell.application
      $folderitems = get-childitem $zZipFileName
      foreach($archive in $folderitems){
        $archive.name.substring(0,$archive.name.length -4)
        $zipFile = $shap.Namespace($archive.fullname) 
        $i = $zipFile.items()
        foreach($si in $i){ 
            if($si.getfolder -ne $null){
                 if($si.name -eq "LR_Front_Upper_Control_Arm"){ 
                     $fileSearch = $si.getfolder.Items()
                     foreach($sii in $fileSearch){
                         if ($sii.name.substring(($sii.name.length - 7),7) -eq "_nl.inp"){
                              $shap.namespace($zZipFileName).copyhere($sii)
                              rename-item ($zZipFileName + "\" + $sii.name) -newname ($archive.name.substring(0,$archive.name.length -4) + ".inp")
                         }
                     }
                 } 
            }
        }
     }
```

Now, this script works fine but I need to pass to it the variable that is given to $zZipFileName and the string "LR_Front_Upper_Control_Arm" from my vba code and I also want to embed this powershell script in my VBA code so that it is all self-contained withing one excel sheet. This will get used by other in my team who don't have a clue about programming and neither I or they don't want to spend time educating them that they have multiple script files and stuff like that.

I will continue researching on my own but was hoping to get a little help here. What I've tried so far with my VBA code is  the below

```
ShellVar = Shell("$zZipFileName = """ & folderPath & """" & vbNewLine & _
      "$shap = new-object -com shell.application" & vbNewLine & _
      "$folderitems = get-childitem $zZipFileName" & vbNewLine & _
      "foreach($archive in $folderitems){" & vbNewLine & _
      "$archive.name.substring(0,$archive.name.length -4)" & vbNewLine & _
      "$zipFile = $shap.Namespace($archive.fullname)" & vbNewLine & _
      "$i = $zipFile.items()" & vbNewLine & _
      "foreach($si in $i){" & vbNewLine & _
      "if($si.getfolder -ne $null){" & vbNewLine & _
      "if($si.name -eq """ & targetFolderName & """){" & vbNewLine & _
      "$fileSearch = $si.getfolder.Items()" & vbNewLine & _
      "foreach($sii in $fileSearch){" & vbNewLine & _
      "if ($sii.name.substring(($sii.name.length - 7),7) -eq ""_nl.inp""){" & vbNewLine & _
      "$shap.namespace($zZipFileName).copyhere($sii)" & vbNewLine & _
      "rename-item ($zZipFileName + ""\"" + $sii.name) -newname ($archive.name.substring(0,$archive.name.length -4) + "".inp"")" & vbNewLine & _
      "}" & vbNewLine & _
      "}" & vbNewLine & _
      "}" & vbNewLine & _
      "}" & vbNewLine & _
      "}" & vbNewLine & _
      "}", vbHide)
```

To try and see how it works more small scare and getting a hint that you first need to put the cmd window into powershell mode I tried this small command:

```
Shell "powershell && new-item 'C:\Users\ccapsun2\Desktop\New loads formatting\load decks\LR_Front_Upper_Control_Arm' -itemtype directory", vbNormalFocus
```

good old internet suggesting that using && will make the cmd window engage the commands sequentially but again, it didn't work.

I have also tried the suggestion at the below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539489/how-to-enter-multiple-line-of-code-in-cmd-from-vba) with no success as well.

I have been making slow progress at the expense of frustration for about 3 days now. Any help would be much appreciated. I am probably gonna have a mental breakdown and start crying soon haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer to your Powershell problem, but here's how you'd do it in VBA.
I like this non-recursive approach to traversing "regular" (non-zipped) subfolders, and managed to adapt it to work with a zip archive.

Adjust to suit!

```
Public Sub UnzipSpecificFiles()

    Const LOCAL_ZIP As Variant = "C:\_Stuff\temp\test.zip"
    Const DEST_FLDR As Variant = "C:\_Stuff\temp\"

    Dim Sh As Object, ns, itm, colFolders, fldr

    Set Sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    Set colFolders = New Collection '<< zip folders to be processed
    colFolders.Add LOCAL_ZIP     '<<    ...starting here

    Do While colFolders.Count > 0
        Set fldr = Sh.Namespace(colFolders(1))
        colFolders.Remove 1
        For Each itm In fldr.Items
            If itm.IsFolder Then
                'add this subfolder to the collection for processing
                colFolders.Add fldr.self.Path & "\" & itm.Name
            Else
                'is a file, so see if it's the one we want...
                If itm.Name Like "*_nl.inp" Then
                    Debug.Print itm.Name
                    Sh.Namespace(DEST_FLDR).CopyHere itm
                    Exit Do '<< if you only expect one match
                End If
            End If
        Next itm
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim ! Very simple and elegant solution. You made it look like a piece of cake. I've been searching for something like this for a while but I couldn't figure it out with what I found. I had made the shell thing work as well by creating a powershell script file and running it but this is much faster and also I couldn't figure out how to make the VBA script wait until the powershell script finished. I tried `ShellVar.Run "powershell ""C:\Temp\temp.ps1""", vbNormalFocus, WaitOnReturn` but it wasn't waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Tim's answer is a lot better than my overly complicated solution but if anyone ever wonders how to get it to work I changed the code to be like the below.

```
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim b
Set b = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set a = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\temp.ps1")
a.WriteLine ("$zZipFileName = '" & folderPath & "'")
a.WriteLine ("      $shap = new-object -com shell.application")
a.WriteLine ("      $folderitems = get-childitem $zZipFileName")
a.WriteLine ("      foreach($archive in $folderitems){")
a.WriteLine ("        $archive.name.substring(0,$archive.name.length -4)")
a.WriteLine ("        $zipFile = $shap.Namespace($archive.fullname)")
a.WriteLine ("        $i = $zipFile.items()")
a.WriteLine ("        foreach($si in $i){")
a.WriteLine ("            if($si.getfolder -ne $null){")
a.WriteLine ("                 if($si.name -eq '" & targetFolderName & "'){")
a.WriteLine ("                     $fileSearch = $si.getfolder.Items()")
a.WriteLine ("                     foreach($sii in $fileSearch){")
a.WriteLine ("                         if ($sii.name.substring(($sii.name.length - 7),7) -eq '_nl.inp'){")
a.WriteLine ("                              $shap.namespace($zZipFileName).copyhere($sii)")
a.WriteLine ("                              rename-item ($zZipFileName + '\' + $sii.name) -newname ($archive.name.substring(0,$archive.name.length -4) + '.inp')")
a.WriteLine ("                         }")
a.WriteLine ("                     }")
a.WriteLine ("                 }")
a.WriteLine ("            }")
a.WriteLine ("         }")
a.WriteLine ("      }")

ShellVar.Run "powershell ""C:\Temp\temp.ps1""", vbNormalFocus
```

The last problem with this is that I couldn't figure out how to make the VBA code wait for the powershell script to finish. I tried adding `, WaitOnReturn` at the end of the .Run command but it wasn't waiting. If that would be fixed then I'd only add something to get rid of the script file created. Something like `Kill a`.

folderPath and targetFolderName are variables passed from the main macro.