# Call terminal from VBA (Linux)

Tags: linux, vba, shell, excel

I'm trying to run a script from Excel in Linux- is this possible? I used `playonlinux` to setup MS Office on Linux and tried the following simple code (originally from [Execute a command in command prompt using excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba)):

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run "cmd.exe /c Z:/home/(me)/Downloads/test.sh"
```

but I get an `Error 13: Type Mismatch`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the type mismatch exception?

Comment: On the last line- even the line `wsh.Run "cmd.exe"` throws the error.