# Call a python function from vba

Tags: python, vba

I am trying to call a python function in a `.py` file in VBA.

I use this command to open the python shell :

```
Pathctrl = "C:\users\test\Desktop"
ChDir Pathctrl
Call Shell(Pathctrl & "\anaconda_python.bat ", vbNormalFocus)
```

I don't know how to write a VBA command to run a specific function within a python shell.

Answer (score 2):

This is a VBA question (and not related to Python).

According to @Ripster, in [Execute a command in command prompt using excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba?answertab=active#tab-top), you can call a Script with `Call Shell(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, in my Python script, I have different defined functions, I just don't know how to call one of those defined functions within vba.