# Starting from Excel (VBA): Launch an external interactive program, and in there launch commands and read their output : is this possible?

Tags: excel, vba, external-process

Currently I'm doing the following for analysing a memory leak:

1. I open both dumps, using Windbg.
2. I launch heap_stat script, a Python-based script for making a summary of the objects, used in the heap.
3. I copy the results of both heap_stat scripts, and paste them in an Excel sheet, where the results are analysed.

I'd like to automate this, starting from the final Excel sheet, using VBA, as follows:

1. Start two instances of an external program (`Windbg.exe`) and open both dumps with them.
2. In those `Windbg` instances, launch the necessary commands (`.load pykd.pykd`, followed by `.py heap_stat.py -stat`).
3. Wait for the `heap_stat.py` script to finish, and copy the result to the Excel sheet.
4. Add some necessary `Match()` worksheet functions and Excel formulas for completing the analysis.

In order to do this, I need to be able to:

1. Launch an external program from VBA. This can be done, using the `Shell` command.
2. Within that external program, launch two other commands. (Launching one command is easy, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba), but what about two?) In case this is not possible: `Windbg` allows concatenating commands, using a semi-colon, so that can be skipped. In order to perform this, I'm thinking about the trick, explained in mentioned URL.
3. Wait for everything to be finished. This can be done using [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx).
4. Read the output.

My issue is : is it possible to read the output? I know it is possible to wait for a command to finish, to verify if the result is ok or if there is an error, but I don't find a way to read the actual output, thrown by the command.

Does anybody know if this is (easily) feasible?

Comment: Why not dump your output to a text file and direct excel to read the output from said text file?

Comment: @TateGarringer: great idea! That's exactly what I'll do. Unfortunately in the meanwhile I've stumbled on another issue: I thought it would be easy to launch a command within my external program (`Windbg`), but this seems not to be easy: the result of the `Shell` command gives the PID of the external program. Do you know how I can launch a command to an external program, using its PID?

Comment: I'm personally unfamiliar with `Windbg`, so I'm not sure if passing arguments via `Shell()` would warrant the same syntax as, say, passing arguments to the command prompt. You may have better luck posting as a separate question.

Comment: Could you not use a script to launch your program with commands (i.e. Python) and then read the output once the script completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found following solution to my problem:

- I'll adapt my heap_stat script, at the end it'll create an empty (flag) file.
- I'll windbg from Excel VBA as follows:

  ```
  Shell "windbg -z ""C:\Directory\Dumpfile.dmp"" -c "".load pykd.pyd;.logopen C:\Directory\output.txt;!py heap_stat.py -stat""", vbMaximizedFocus
  ```

  - The meaning of the Windbg commands is the following:

    ```
    .load pykd.pyd         // load PYKD library
    .logopen ...           // open a logfile, for all Windbg output (thanks, Zac and Tate, for the idea)
    !py heap_stat.py -stat // launch the heap_stat script
    ```
- I'll write a `while`-loop, verifying for the presence of the flag file.
- The output file's content will be copied to the Excel file, which will do the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pykd for fully automatic tasks, why you need to run it inside windbg?
You can make a standalone python script.