# How to launch `LogOpen` Windbg command from commandline

Tags: command-line, windbg

This is a followup question on "[How to use Windbg for opening a dump and launching some Windbg commands from the command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293393/how-to-use-windbg-for-opening-a-dump-and-launching-some-windbg-commands-from-the)".

I've managed getting my system working, but in case of filenames, containing a space, I can't get it to work. I'm dealing with a dumpfile, called `E:\Spaced FileName.dmp`, which I'd like to open, and I'd like to write the logs to `E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt`. I already tried the following:

```
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt"
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt""
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen ""E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt"""
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen 'E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt'"
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen ''E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt''"
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen "'E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt'""
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen \"E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt\""
Prompt>windbg -z "E:\Spaced FileName.dmp" -c ".load pykd.pyd;.logopen (E:\Spaced FileName.dmp.txt)"
```

None of them was working, by which I mean: it was ok opening the dumpfile, but setting the logfile was erroneous.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a directory with spaces and copying a dmp file by renaming it with spaces

```
C:\>md "my space filled gas"

C:\>cd "my space filled gas"

C:\my space filled gas>ls -l
total 26544
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0 27180255 2019-02-26 22:36 my gas filled space.dmp
```

opening the dmp file in windbg with some command and log

```
C:\my space filled gas>windbg -z "my gas filled space.dmp" -logo "my gas filled space.dmp.txt" -c "lm;q"
```

result

```
C:\my space filled gas>ls -l
total 26552
-rw-rw-rw-  1  0 27180255 2019-02-26 22:36 my gas filled space.dmp
-rw-rw-rw-  1  0     4647 2019-02-26 22:40 my gas filled space.dmp.txt
```

checking whats dumped in the log file

```
C:\my space filled gas>grep -A 5 -i lm;q "my gas filled space.dmp.txt"
0:000> lm;q
start    end        module name
00880000 00940000   calc       (deferred)
69310000 69342000   winmm      (deferred)
6bfc0000 6bfd0000   aswhook    (deferred)
73b70000 73d00000   GdiPlus    (deferred)

C:\my space filled gas>
```