# Feasibility of Running .jar with VBA and Excel

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have a .jar file which I want to run from an Excel sheet using VBA. Ideally, this could be done on both Windows and Mac with only one set of code.

To run the .jar file, I call it from the command line/terminal with `java -cp somejar.jar outputResults/something`. Then, I enter a String through the command line to specify the starting user in my simulation. Finally, I enter either 0 or 1 to specify the type of function used. After this a results file is generated.

It seems this [may be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba) with Shell, but the linked example only provides an example for a single line entered, not multiple. Is this feasible and, if so, can someone point me towards an example?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for :

```
#!/bin/bash
"$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java -jar /root/jeevee/bin/deploy.jar
```

Comment: Is this code for a .command or .bat file or VBA? When I enter it into VBA, I get an error.

Comment: This is for shell as you asked.