# Creating a LDIF file from CSV or Excel sheet

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My Requirement is like, we will ask requester to fill an excel sheet/csv where they will put the values in column uiddn(A1 in excel sheet) and nIds(B1 in excel sheet).

For Example:
[image]

uiddn nIds
uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx 7_54321
uid=uid6789,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx 5_9876

Once those details are filled, a bash script should take the values and create a ldif in the name 'removenid.ldif' and the ldif should content as shown below:

```
dn: uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: nIds
nIds: 7_54321
-

dn: uid=uid6789,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: nIds
nIds: 5_9876
-
```

Along with it should create another ldif file in the name 'groupremoval.ldif' where the ldif file content should be:

```
dn: cn=ghk,cn=klm,cn=opu,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: member
member: uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx---only this value it should take from the excel sheet

dn: cn=ghk,cn=klm,cn=opu,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: member
member: uid=uid6789,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx---only this value it should take from the excel sheet
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You are expected to show what you have tried, and how it fails.  Research is on you.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  That being said, you need to read your CSV, line per line, extract each item into variables, and printf the new lines you want.  `awk` is your friend here.

Comment: @Satyajit – It looks like you don't have comma separated values – what is the separator?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Armali, is it not possible through excel sheet data.

Answer (score 0):

Step one is to save your table from Excel to a **CSV**.

I strongly recommend **specifying a delimiter character** (*in this case vertical bar* "**|**") because you never know when your input will deliberately have spaces in any of the fields.  *So, a space character is the worst choice*.

You would need to **create a macro** to automatically save the *.CSV file with a constantly reused file name (i.e. **always iddnx.csv**).

Then, again using the macro, tell the OS to run the script with the required parameters.

- [**This**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8) talks about how to create a macro.
- [**This**](https://excelchamps.com/vba/run-macro/) talks about how to run the macro.
- [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba) talks about how you can get the OS to run the command.

**The following script** will generate the two files indicated:

```
#!/bin/bash

DBG=0
input=""

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --debug ) DBG=1 ; shift ;;
        --input ) input="${2}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --strAlt ) strAlt="${2}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n Invalid option use on command line.  Only valid options: [ --debug | --input {inputfile} ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${input}" ]
then
    echo -e "\n DEMO RUN ..."
    input=iddnx.csv
    cat >"${input}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
uiddn|nIds
uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx|7_54321
uid=uid6789,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx|5_9876
EnDoFiNpUt
    strAlt="cn=ghk,cn=klm,cn=opu"
fi

if [ -z "${strAlt}" ]
then
    echo -e "\n ERROR - missing option '--strAlt' requires string value to be specified!\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1
fi

output1="removenid.ldif"
output2="groupremoval.ldif"

awk -v dbg=${DBG} -v altStr="${strAlt}" -v f1="${output1}" -v f2="${output2}" 'BEGIN{
    ## Initial loading of the report reference index file into an array for tabulation
    split( "", dataload );
    indexR=0 ;
    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\n\t --- %s\n", "PHASE 1" ) | "cat >&2" ; } ;
}
{
    if( $0 != "" ){
        indexR++ ;
        split( $0, datline, "|" );
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\n\t --- %s\n", $0 ) | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        dataload[indexR,1]=datline[1] ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t --- datline[1] = %s\n", datline[1] ) | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        dataload[indexR,2]=datline[2] ;
        if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\t --- datline[2] = %s\n", datline[2] ) | "cat >&2" ; } ;

        if( indexR == 1 ){
            typeHdr=datline[2] ;
        } ;
    } ;
}
END{
    if( dbg == 1 ){ printf("\n\t --- %s\n", "PHASE 2" ) | "cat >&2" ; } ;
    for( i=2 ; i<=indexR ; i++ ){
        #dn: uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
        #changetype: modify
        #delete: nIds
        #nIds: 7_54321
        #-
        printf("dn: %s\nchangetype: modify\ndelete: %s\n%s: %s\n-\n\n", dataload[i,1], typeHdr, typeHdr, dataload[i,2] ) >f1 ;
    } ;

    for( i=2 ; i<=indexR ; i++ ){
        split( dataload[i,1], tmp, "," ) ;
        #dn: cn=ghk,cn=klm,cn=opu,dc=xyx
        #changetype: modify
        #delete: member
        #member: uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
        #
        printf("dn: %s,%s\nchangetype: modify\ndelete: member\nmember: %s\n\n", altStr, tmp[4], dataload[i,1] ) >f2 ;
    } ;
}' "${input}" 

echo -e "\nLDIF files generated:"
ls -l "${output1}" "${output2}"

echo -e "\nContents of '${output1}':\n"
cat "${output1}"

echo -e "\nContents of '${output2}':\n"
cat "${output2}"
```

Using the command line:

```
script.sh --input iddnx.csv --strAlt "cn=ggg,cn=kkk,cn=ppp"
```

You will get the following output:

```
LDIF files generated:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 217 Feb  8 16:35 groupremoval.ldif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 172 Feb  8 16:35 removenid.ldif

Contents of 'removenid.ldif':

dn: uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: nIds
nIds: 7_54321
-

dn: uid=uid6789,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: nIds
nIds: 5_9876
-


Contents of 'groupremoval.ldif':

dn: cn=ggg,cn=kkk,cn=ppp,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: member
member: uid=uid12345,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx

dn: cn=ggg,cn=kkk,cn=ppp,dc=xyx
changetype: modify
delete: member
member: uid=uid6789,cn=abc,cn=def,dc=xyx
```