# Graphic from xlsx to be used by python

Tags: excel, xlrd, win32com

I need to call for graphicall object ( basically a picture inserted to excel spreadsheet). Does anybody know how to do it? xlrd or win32com or  something  specific?

Answer (score 0):

it looks  like  I found workaround. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232987/export-pictures-from-excel-file-into-jpg-using-vba) is an example of  extraction images from excel using  VBA macro and as pics  saved I can call for them from python