# SSIS: Export images embedded in Excel

Tags: ssis

I have a VB6 application that takes an Excel spreadsheet with 2 worksheets, one for data and one for images, and saves the data and exports the images to a folder.

I would like to move this to SSIS but I can't find a way to export the images to a folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Besides asking on SO, what research or work have you done to address this?

Comment: I did my web searches prior and only found references to ADDING images to Excel and not exporting FROM via SSIS.

Comment: Why do you want to move it to SSIS? That's a bad idea. Move it to a C# console app.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export the images to the file server and then import them.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00b71581-cc36-4614-b6a9-4fc13c3220fe/import-images-in-excel-file-to-sql-database?forum=sqlintegrationservices

[Export pictures from excel file into jpg using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232987/export-pictures-from-excel-file-into-jpg-using-vba)

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/imageimportexport/