# VBA - Export Image from Excel *without* using Clipboard (Copy/Paste)

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks, clipboard

There are a lot of great examples of how to take an Excel range, create an image from it, and save it to the drive. Here is one: [Export pictures from excel file into jpg using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232987/export-pictures-from-excel-file-into-jpg-using-vba)

This works great on a small scale, but when you try to run this through 3,000 or more iterations, a "memory leak" caused by the repeated use of the clipboard eventually erodes the process and the macro fails somewhere along the way. This occurs even when running 64-bit Excel on a powerful machine (50+ GB of RAM).

Are there any ways to do this without using the clipboard?? My first thought was to try to fix the memory leak issue, but all of those attempts have been unsuccessful. For context, I'm basically using the exact code as provided in the solution on link above (with a couple of added features to try to reduce memory leaking like auto-saving the workbook after every 100 images, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was ultimately no solution for the memory leak, it seems to be a systemic problem with VBA.

For those trying to programmatically generate charts, it is much easier to build in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for what you mentioned; here's how to do it with a chart:

```
Dim file As String ' the path to the saved image, in the temp dir
file = Environ$("temp") & "\chart.gif"

Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(0).Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(0).Chart.Export Filename:=file, FilterName:="GIF"
```