# I have an Excel file in column A serial number in column B ID Number, in Column 3 photograph of a person

Tags: vba, image, export

I have an Excel file. In sheet1 column A is serial number, column B is ID Number, Column C is image of a person, and column D is Name.
I want to export photograph to C/temp in jpg format, in the place of name I need their ID number which is in column B.

in VBA, there are more than 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The photographs are Shape objects. For code to export them, look at the answers to this question, [Export pictures from excel file into jpg using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234074/6387947).