# Wait for windows CMD to finish inside of vba

Tags: excel, cmd, vba

Is it possible to run a windows command prompt terminal command in VBA but also tell VBA to wait until this command is finished before continuing on in the procedure? If so, how?

Comment: Hi yes I've seen this only it doesn't discuss how to deal with continued execution of VBA code after a windows cmd command of unknown time has finished

Comment: I managed to solve this by piping the terminal command to a file and having VBA use a do while loop which repeatedly waited while file not found

Comment: The top answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/wait-for-shell-command-to-complete (using WScript.Shell) works well.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by piping the terminal command to a file and having VBA use a do while loop which repeatedly waited while file not found