# Excel VBA - Print exisiting PDF file then delete when printed

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel to compile existing PDF files and email them or print them depending on the recipients preferred method of contact.

Once the code (below) has run I would like the files to be deleted. I have tried to use the Kill function, but am finding that I get the error "Run-time error '70' - Permission denied".

I'm assuming this is because at least one of the files is still being used by Acrobat Reader when the kill function attempts to delete. I've used the kill function separately to the main code and it seems to work ok.

Is there a way to pause the code until the printing is completed?

Many thanks in advance......

```
    Option Explicit

    Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
        ByVal hwnd As Long, _
        ByVal lpOperation As String, _
        ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, _
        ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
        ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
        As Long

    Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String)

    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

    End Sub

    Sub SEND_BUDGETS()

    Dim FILE_NAME As String
    Dim OUT_APP As Outlook.Application
    Dim OUT_MAIL As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim C As String
    Dim YEAR_END As Integer
    Dim PROP_FOLDER As String

    If Sheet2.Range("A1").Value <> "ref" Then

        MsgBox ("Invalid data entered - Please try again")

        Exit Sub

    End If


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheet1.Visible = True

    YEAR_END = InputBox("Please enter service charge period end year")

    PROP_FOLDER = Sheet2.Range("A2") & " - " & Sheet2.Range("B2")

    If Dir("G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then

        MkDir "G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER

        MkDir "G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END

    Else

        If Dir("G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then

            MsgBox ("Folder for year end " & YEAR_END & " already exists - Please try again")

            Sheet1.Visible = xlVeryHidden

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            Exit Sub

        Else

            MkDir "G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END

        End If

    End If


    'GET LIST OF FILES FROM "FILES TO SEND" FOLDER

    Sheet1.Range("A2:A2000").ClearContents

    FILE_NAME = Dir("G:\accounts\Service Charge Budget Emailer\Files To Send\" & "*.*")

    Sheet1.Activate

    Sheet1.Range("A2").Activate

    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Do While Len(FILE_NAME) > 0

        ActiveCell.Value = FILE_NAME

        FILE_NAME = Dir

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll


    'CHECK IF FILES HAVE BEEN FOUND

    If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "FILE LIST - 0" Then

        Sheet1.Visible = xlVeryHidden

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Sheet2.Select

        MsgBox ("Please add files to:-" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "G:\accounts\Service Charge Budget Emailer\Files To Send\")

        Exit Sub

    End If


    'SEND EMAILS

    Set OUT_APP = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

     If Err.Number = 429 Then

        Set OUT_APP = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

     End If


    On Error Resume Next

    For A = 2 To Range("D2001").End(xlUp).Row

        Set OUT_MAIL = OUT_APP.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        If Sheet1.Range("N" & A).Value = "EMAIL" Then

            With OUT_MAIL

            .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear Proprietor,<p>" _
                            & "Please find attached service charge budget and any related paperwork in reference to the subject property.<p>" _
                            & "Kind regards,<p>"
             .To = Cells(A, 15).Value
             .Subject = Cells(A, 16).Value & " - Year Ending " & YEAR_END
             .Attachments.Add Cells(A, 9).Value
             .Attachments.Add Cells(A, 10).Value
             .Attachments.Add Cells(A, 11).Value
             .Attachments.Add Cells(A, 12).Value
             .Attachments.Add Cells(A, 13).Value
             .SaveAs "G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END & "\" & Cells(A, 16) & " - Year Ending " & YEAR_END & ".msg", OlSaveAsType.olMSG
             .Send

            End With

        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("N" & A).Value = "PRINT" Then

            On Error GoTo 0

            For B = 9 To 13

                If Cells(A, B) <> "" Then

                    C = Cells(A, B).Value

                    PrintFile (C)

                    If Dir("G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END & "\" & Cells(A, 16), vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then

                        MkDir "G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END & "\" & Cells(A, 16)

                    End If

                    FileCopy C, "G:\accounts\Service Charge Team\Sent Budget Packs\P" & PROP_FOLDER & "\" & YEAR_END & "\" & Cells(A, 16) & "\" & Cells(A, B - 5)

                End If

            Next B

        End If

    Next A

    Kill ("G:\accounts\Service Charge Budget Emailer\Files To Send\" & "*.*")

    Sheet1.Visible = xlVeryHidden

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("Complete")
```

Comment: Check [Getting the status of the selected printer from Visual Basic](http://www.merrioncomputing.com/Programming/PrintStatus.htm)

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952009/78522

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I am struggling to implement the suggestions in my code. The "WScript.Shell" suggestion seems promising, but the example opens an application itself, but in my code the application seems to open with the apiShellExextute function. Can I use the "WScript.Shell" to wait for an application that is already open? Perhaps incorporate it into the PrintFile sub?