# Call .com file with parameters using VBA WScript.Shell

Tags: excel, vba, winscp, windows-scripting

I'm using Excel to upload some files onto an server with WinSCP.
This example works:

```
Sub FTP_upload()
    Dim logfile, ftp_login, file_to_upload, upload_to_folder As String
    logfile = "D:\temp\ftp.log"
    ftp_login = "ftp://ftp_mydomain:mypassword@mydomain.com/"
    file_to_upload = "D:\tmep\myfile.txt"
    upload_to_folder = "/myfolder/"

    'upload the file
    Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /log=" & logfile & " /command " & """open """ & ftp_login & " " & """put " & file_to_upload & " " & upload_to_folder & """ " & """exit""")
End Sub
```

I now want Excel to wait until the shell has closed.

Using the information from [Wait for shell command to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/wait-for-shell-command-to-complete), I put it together this code:

```
Sub FTP_upload_with_wait()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode  As Integer

    Dim logfile, ftp_login, file_to_upload, upload_to_folder As String
    logfile = "D:\temp\ftp.log"
    ftp_login = "ftp://ftp_mydomain:mypassword@mydomain.com/"
    file_to_upload = "D:\tmep\myfile.txt"
    upload_to_folder = "/myfolder/"

    execute_string = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /log=" & logfile & " /command " & """open """ & ftp_login & " " & """put " & file_to_upload & " " & upload_to_folder & """ " & """exit"""

    errorCode = wsh.Run(execute_string, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Excel reports:

> run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)'
>   Automation error
>   The system cannot find the file specified

When I replace the string this way, it works:

```
execute_string = "notepad.exe"
```

It seems that `wsh.Run` doesn't like the quotation marks.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to WinSCP contains spaces, so you need to wrap it to double-quotes (which need to be doubled to escape them in VBA string):

```
execute_string = """C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" ..."
```

But that's only the first set of quotes that is wrong in your command.

The correct command would be like:

```
execute_string = """C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"" " & _
    "/log=" & logfile & " /command " & _
    """open " & ftp_login & """ " & _
    """put " & file_to_upload & " " & upload_to_folder & """ " & _
    """exit"""
```

Assuming that none of `logfile`, `ftp_login`, `file_to_upload` and `upload_to_folder` contains spaces, in which case would would need a way more double-quotes.

Read ore about [WinSCP command-line syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax)

---

The `Call Shell` must have some heuristics that adds the quotes around `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com`. Though it's just a pure luck that the rest of the command-line works, the quotes are wrong there too. So even your first code is wrong. It runs the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /log=D:\temp\ftp.log /command "open "ftp://ftp_mydomain:mypassword@mydomain.com/ "put D:\tmep\myfile.txt /myfolder/" "exit"
```

(Note the misplaced quotes around `open`)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim objShell, oExec
    Set objShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    Set oExec = objShell.Exec(".....")
    Status = oExec.Status
    'waiting for return.
    While oExec.Status <= 0
    Wend
    ProcessID = oExec.ProcessID
    ExitCode = oExec.ExitCode
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).