# close every step in VBA before go to the other step

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I wrote a VBA-code which uses a `batch` to copy some files from **A** to **B** and then run Access-macros  which use the copied files in **B**. After running the macros the VBA-code  the queries results from Access into the excel.

```
' run the batch
    RetVal = Shell("I:\myW\k1ltios1_k1ltit31_Kopie.bat", 1)

' ============================
' run the macros in ACCESS

Dim accessApp
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")  'define an Access object

accessApp.Visible = True 'hold Access object open

accessApp.UserControl = True
.
.
.
' <<< copy the results from Access into th eExcel files >>>
'#Enter  the valus of cells in the arrays
i = 0
ReDim marrSql(0)
 For Each cell In Worksheets("eingaben").Range("B20:B21")
    marrSql(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve marrSql(i)
    Debug.Print marrSql(i)
Next


i = 0
ReDim marrPlace(0)
 For Each cell In Worksheets("eingaben").Range("A20:A21")
    marrPlace(i) = cell
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve marrPlace(i)
Next
'# end of entering

For i = 0 To 1
'
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & marrSql(i) & "];"

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmdCommand As ADODB.Command
.
.
.

Next
```

If I run the code it works well but all windows (batch, Access and Excel) open immediately together! 
**Now my question**: How is it possible to start the *batch* and if there is no error it should be closed then run the macros in *Access* and generate the queries if there is no problem copy the results into Excel and then close the Access? I want to be sure that the steps are done one after each other because otherwise the code would peek up the old results in one or another step!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439200/vba-shell-and-wait-with-exit-code or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells