# MS Access VBA get result of WinSCP transfer

Tags: ms-access, ftp, vba, winscp

I have code that uploads a folder to an FTP server using WinSCP.

```
Dim strSFTPDir As String
strSFTPDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\"
Dim UploadsDir As String
UploadsDir = DLookup("PathToPics", "Admin") & "\Uploads\*"
Call Shell(strSFTPDir & "winscp.com /command ""open ftp://***/"" ""put -filemask=|*.ldb """"" & UploadsDir & """"" "" ""exit"" ", vbNormalFocus)
```

However I need to let Access know whether it's succeeded or failed.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP indicates a result with its exit code.
See WinSCP FAQ [How do I know that script completed successfully?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_result)

So run WinSCP and make sure it returns 0 (success).
See [VBA Shell and Wait with Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1439200/850848)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the code in that link is long and confusing and I'm not sure what parts exactly I need? Does my original Call Shell() code need to be changed entirely?

Comment: You need to replace your `Shell` call with what the `RunApplication` function does in the linked code. There's no easier way in VBA. - If you do not explain us, what you find *"confusing"* about the code, we cannot help you on that.