# Best way to handshake between VBA to Python

Tags: python, vba, shell, interop, solidworksapi

I'm trying to automate a program (solidworks) using python via VBA.

I am executing the python script using shell32. However the problem I have is I want the VBA script to wait until the python script is done before it terminates.

Right now the VBA script is done as soon as it makes the call

Does anyone have an idea of a good way to perform this handshake?

Comment: Always helps to post your existing code...

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1439200/5162073) will help.